# Order of div on mobile

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a page(using bootstrap3) that looks like this(1st image) on browsers.
[image]

It looks like this(2nd image) on mobiles
[image]

But what I want is to have the divs in the following order on mobiles keeping orders same in browsers...... 
SEARCHBOX
MAP
SEARCH FILTER
SEARCH RESULTS

Thanks in advance

Comment: ok.. where is your code? post it here..

Comment: Also post the related css code here..

Comment: That's all. All CSSs are defined inline. Nothing in the external sheet.

Comment: Then it is working fine. I mean in the browsers it is visible to me as the second image which you have posted above. even if I resize.

Comment: I want the order of the divs to be like this...SEARCHBOX-MAP-SEARCH FILTER-SEARCH RESULTS.... Current code orders div in this order SEARCHBOX-MAP- SEARCH RESULTS  -SEARCH FILTER

Comment: you can do that by changing HTML. Can't you change the html?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37570/discussion-between-reccur-nishan-and-mr-green)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Possible to achieve this Mobile/Desktop layout using Bootstrap? (or other grid)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542303/possible-to-achieve-this-mobile-desktop-layout-using-bootstrap-or-other-grid)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [Possible to achieve this Mobile/Desktop layout using Bootstrap? (or other grid)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542303/possible-to-achieve-this-mobile-desktop-layout-using-bootstrap-or-other-grid/18547041) and with the use of nesting (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting)

**css**

```
.floatright{float:right;}
@media (max-width: 992px)
{    
    .floatright{float:none;}
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color:aqua;">Search box</div>
                <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color:yellow;">Map</div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 floatright" style="background-color:red; height:200px;"> Search Filter</div>

                <div class="col-md-8" style="background-color:green;"> Search search results</div>

            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much... I was wondering if we could have a solution without using media query.

Comment: I don't think so. You will have to look to the col-*-push-*/col-*-pull-* or col-*-offset-* classes. You could apply this classes on all grids ecept from the xs-grid. Try http://bootply.com/81911 as start point to find a solution which fits your needs. These alternatives all have the same result for the xs-grid (mobile < 768px) but not on the larger grids. NOTE These Bootstrap's classes will also use media queries.