# Bootstrap 3 grid system responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid-layout

I am trying to make my user profile responsive using Bootstrap 3. A very simplified example of my profile is here: http://jsfiddle.net/RRfSW/5/

On desktops it is important that the boxes 1 and 2 are at the top because they contain the most relevant information.
On mobile devices the box 2 should be just below box 1 - same reason. But as you can see by resizing the example it will be below box 3.

Of course i could simply put boxes 1 and 2 on a div[class=row] but as you can see the boxes are not same height and i would waste much space on desktops.

how can i handle this problem?

```
<div class="row">
<div id="leftBar" class="col-md-7">

    <div id="mainProfile" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            1
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="details" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">  
            3                
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">                    
        </div>
    </div>

</div>


<div id="rightBar" class="col-md-5">
    <div id="contact" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">   
            2                
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="other" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">     
            4               
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check out http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid there is some information with regards to using differnt column classes for different sizes.

Comment: really? As to me it looks like you've just use the md class for everything rather than the more specific xs and sm classes meant for mobiles and tablets?

Comment: Those classes do not solve my specific problem. You may proof me wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Order of div on mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18865478/order-of-div-on-mobile)

Answer (score 1):

Remove extra row class and add some more device specific classes like,

```
col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-6
```

Check the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7WMBr/1/)

Check documentation [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Comment: Well there is exactly the problem i mentioned: A gap between box 1 and 3.

Comment: That's because you added different height for divs. Check updated fiddle in the answer. http://jsfiddle.net/7WMBr/1/

Comment: But that is exactly the point! The divs will have different height as content is added by the user.

Answer (score 0):

For me your question seems identical of [Order of div on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18865478/order-of-div-on-mobile/18867179) so i will also vote for duplicate.

In your case, see http://bootply.com/82040

**css**

```
#mainProfile {
    background-color: #ccaaaa;
    height:200px;
}

#details {
    background-color: #aaccaa;
    height:180px;
}

#contact {
    background-color: #cc66ff;
    height:300px;
}

#other {
    background-color: #aaaacc;
    height:180px;
}    

.floatright{float:right;}
@media (max-width: 992px)
{    
    .floatright{float:none;}
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="leftBar" class="col-md-7">

        <div id="mainProfile" class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
1               main profile
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
    <div id="rightBar2" class="col-md-5 floatright">
        <div id="contact" class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">   2                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<div id="leftBar" class="col-md-7">
        <div id="details" class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6"> 3 details           
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">    ???                
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>


<div id="rightBar" class="col-md-5">
        <div id="other" class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">     4               
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```