# Article push/pull alignment using bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap 3 and I try to have a specific grid alignment for article on desktop.

On mobile I want to order content of the article like that :

1. Title
2. Image
3. Content

On desktop, I want the image on the left and the title and content on the right.

[image: Alignment i want]

Here is my code

```
<article class="row">
    <header class="col-md-8 col-md-push-4">
        <a href="#">
            <h2>Title</h2>
        </a>
    </header>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-8">
        <figure>
            <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
        <img src="..." alt="4x3 Image" class="img-responsive">
                <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
            </a>
        </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-push-4">
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
</article>
```

But with this code, the content is on the right but under the image.

[image]

Is there a simple way to get what I want ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Order of div on mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18865478/order-of-div-on-mobile)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on [Possible to achieve this Mobile/Desktop layout using Bootstrap? (or other grid)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542303/possible-to-achieve-this-mobile-desktop-layout-using-bootstrap-or-other-grid/18547041)

**css:**

```
.floatright{float:right;}
@media (max-width: 768px)
{    
    .floatright{float:none;}
}
```

**html:**

```
<div class="container" style="background-color:green">
<article class="row">
    <header class="col-md-8 floatright">
        <a href="#">
            <h2>Title</h2>
        </a>
    </header>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <figure>
            <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
        <img src="..." alt="4x3 Image" class="img-responsive">
                <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
            </a>
        </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 floatright">
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
</article>
</div>
```

Comment: I've done something like that to resolve my problem.I've created a `.pull-left-md`and `.pull-right-md` class

Answer (score 1):

it's your columns class:

md:
4 (image) - 8 (title) => 1st row (max 12 columns)

8 (content) => new row

that's will make a new row, the 2nd row placed below image/title column

so you must use this columns setting (using hidden class) like this:

md:
2 (image) - 5 (title) - 5 (hidden-xs hidden-sm)

5 (content)

just try this code:

**CSS:**

```
<style>
        .col-md-2{
            height: 300px;
            background-color: blue;
            color: white;
            border: 2px solid red;
        }
        .col-md-4{
            height: 100px;
        }
        .col-md-5{
            height: 100px;
            background-color: red;
            color: white;
            border: 2px solid black;
        }
</style>
```

**HTML:**

```
    <article class="row">
        <header class="col-md-5 col-md-push-2">
            <a href="#">
                <h2>Title</h2>
            </a>
        </header>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-pull-5">
            <figure>
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                    <img src="" alt="4x3 Image" class="img-responsive">
                    <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
                </a>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 col-md-pull-5">
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>
    </article>
```

maybe it's not solve the problem. but you can use this trick.

sorry for my bad english

Comment: Generally it's better to provide some explanation alongside your code in an answer, or even no code at all. Give a man a fish and all of that...

Answer (score 0):

Use a bigger div with col-md-8 class and place title and text inside it and use bootstrap's col-md-12 class on both of them to stack over one another

Answer (score 0):

Here's how fix the problem

```
<article class="row">
    <header class="col-md-8 pull-right">
        <a href="#">
            <h2>Title</h2>
        </a>
    </header>
    <div class="col-md-4 pull-left">
        <figure>
            <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
        <img src="..." alt="4x3 Image" class="img-responsive">
                <figcaption>...</figcaption>
            </a>
        </figure>    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 pull-right">
        <p>content</p>
    </div>
</article>
```

Comment: the `pull-right` and `pull-left` are not responsive, so you mobile view don't differs (colums still float)?