# Change column stack order in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem that I'm hoping the Bootstrap grid system can solve, but I can't work out how to do it.

I want my site to show like this on desktop:

`+---------+-------+
| Header  |       |
+---------+ Image |
| Content |       |
+---------+-------+`

And like this on mobile:

`+---------+
| Header  |
+---------+
| Image   |
+---------+
| Content |
+---------+`

I feel like this will be possible with Bootstrap's "pull" and "push" classes but I've tried lots of things and can't get it happening.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think so, `pull` & `push` don't change stacking order...just horizontal position.

Comment: OK, I just assumed `pull` & `push` would be involved because in my research I've seen a lot of similar problems solved with them.

Comment: See updated answer with image spanning 2 rows;

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19046787/article-push-pull-alignment-using-bootstrap-3

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible. For example this layout:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="header col-xs-12 col-sm-6">Header</div>
    <div class="image col-xs-12 col-sm-6">Image</div>
    <div class="content col-xs-12 col-sm-6">Content</div>
</div>
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/KnPd7/

So basically it says:

- for extra-small resolution let header expand to 12 columns (100%)
- for small, medium and large - 6 columns (50%)

and so on for `.image` and `.content` divs.

Classes `col-xx-N` are powered with media queries.

#### UPD

With a little magic it's also quite possible to make image area extend to 100% height of the container.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/KnPd7/1/

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this doesn't seem quite right. Effectively, on desktop, you're giving a 12-element row 18 elements, meaning it overflows to the next line. The consequence is that the desktop shows "header" and "image" on one line and then line breaks before "content". "Image" isn't spanned across the two rows. So that isn't quite right.

Comment: I see. Making .image container to extend to max height of the .row is another task, quite doable.

Comment: `col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6` is redundant and equivalent to simply `col-sm-6`

Comment: I thought this was right, but actually it's not quite. It works when this entire element is at the top of the page, but not when it's in the middle of a page amongst other elements. The "position: absolute; top: 0;" means that it goes to the very top of the page. How can this solution be more robust to work regardless of where it is on the page? Updated fiddle to demonstrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/N5jAG/

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm still having problems applying this solution though. It seems to be broadly because this solution relies on breaking Bootstrap's grid system...but maybe this is the only way. My new problem is illustrated in http://jsfiddle.net/38V7r/ - it's because the old solution relies on the height of various elements to layout properly. Is there any solutions that don't rely on setting manual heights?

Answer (score -1):

In my Idea Bootstrap make this complicated its more easy to do if you write your own classes check `

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/tasaeed/ZSas7/1/`
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the whole point of this is that I want to know how to do it in Bootstrap.