# Bootstrap: changing the order of the column layout in desktop layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

the mobile first layout will be having three columns in a row 3, 9 and 3 respectively(I know total available col are 12, please read full question)

In mobile devices

```
[3]
[9]
[3]
```

But in desktop devices I want to have a layout like

```
[9][3]
   [3]
```

I tried `col-md-pull-3` and `col-md-push-9` but no luck. The third column

I am currently having this done by JS, but hoping for a solution with CSS since it will be lighter.

http://www.bootply.com/8fqIOpmpM7

[image]

solution by @Catalin Munteanu has some limitations.

[image]

Column-2 must have sufficient height to make this work if column-2's height is less than column-1's height column-3 will be floated under column-2.

Comment: Try floating your blue column, as described [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19046787/article-push-pull-alignment-using-bootstrap-3

Comment: I got it, but still the problem occurs in another way http://www.bootply.com/IPKn9GYfxQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your layout should be like this:

```
<div class="container">    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 pull-right">3 cols</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9 pull-right">9 cols</div>        
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 pull-right">3 cols</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit: This should work and remove the gap between those columns:

```
<div class="container">    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 pull-right">3 cols</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9 pull-left">
            <p>THIS</p>
            <p>WON'T</p>
            <p>BREAK</p>
            <p>RIGHT</p>
            <p>FLOATED</p>
            <p>COLUMNS</p>
        </div>        
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 pull-right">3 cols</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zj7Ca/)

Comment: I know their are only 12 columns are allowed, but I need this  http://www.bootply.com/8fqIOpmpM7. I know you are right but some times to achieve some thing you have to break the rules..

Comment: It works.. That's cool dude you make my life easier.... Better add an explanation/description for this.

Comment: still their is a problem if the height of the column-2 is less then column-3 will we add beneath the column-2 instead of column-1