# Need to be able to swap grid on mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Best explained with pictures i believe.
[My website.](http://jackdh.byethost13.com/)
[image]

I have set up a hosting for my website so it is easier to see.

Problem : When on mobile devices due to the way i have it set up it causes the pictures to stack the wrong way like below.

Question : Is there a way I can switch these two col-md 6 's around when the screen is less that X pixels across?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19046787/article-push-pull-alignment-using-bootstrap-3/19048583, use an responsive float:right; : `.floatright{float:right;}
@media (max-width: 768px)
{    
    .floatright{float:none;}
}`

Comment: Hmm I tried this although i could not get it to work. Is there something i may be doing wrong?

Comment: see: http://bootply.com/83645

Comment: Worked brilliantly. I'm happy to accept that as my answer if you want to make it into a official one!

Comment: Do you mind if i ask on line 106 that col-md-6 is not in a row div and yet works why is that?

Comment: Your question will be duplicate of or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19046787/article-push-pull-alignment-using-bootstrap-3/19048583

Comment: possible duplicate of [Possible to achieve this Mobile/Desktop layout using Bootstrap? (or other grid)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542303/possible-to-achieve-this-mobile-desktop-layout-using-bootstrap-or-other-grid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question will be duplicate of [Order of div on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18865478/order-of-div-on-mobile), [Possible to achieve this Mobile/Desktop layout using Bootstrap? (or other grid)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542303/possible-to-achieve-this-mobile-desktop-layout-using-bootstrap-or-other-grid/18547041) or [Article push/pull alignment using bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19046787/article-push-pull-alignment-using-bootstrap-3/19048583) so i will vote for close this too.

In your case you basically do this:

**css:**

.floatright{float:right;} 
@media (max-width: 767px) { .floatright{float:none;} }

Note change 767 to 991 when you use the medium (col-md-*) grid. In your case i should prefer the small grid (col-sm-*) cause the grid-float-breakpoint is set to 767px by default too (see: [Bootstrap 3 Navbar Collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192082/bootstrap-3-navbar-collapse/18944192))

**html:**

```
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">text</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">img</div>
    </div>  
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 floatright">text</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">img</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">text</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">img</div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

You also mentioned "line 106 that col-md-6 is not in a row div". You are right and i was wrong here (typo). The above code is the right one, with column wrapped in rows.
The docs http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed-complete show its not required columns alway sum up to 12. This is not the case here, but the above will also work with all columns in one row like:

```
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">text</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">img</div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 floatright">text</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">img</div>

        <div class="col-sm-6">text</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">img</div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: There was no accepted answer on that Question. I'm not sure if this matters. If it does then this can be closed.

Comment: Also this is not the right place to ask but seeing as SO does not have  a PM feature, do you happen to know where I can read up this sort of thing. IE when the screen < 500px do this etc. Thanks