# Change the order of bootstrap columns on breakpoint

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I currently have this layout:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="row">Content 1</div>
        <div class="row">Content 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="row">Content 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

which gives this:

```
---- --------
|1 | |      |
---- |  3   |
---- |      |
|2 | |      |
---- --------
```

On the col-md breakpoint I want cols to be in this order:

```
------------
|     1    |
------------
------------
|     3    |
------------
------------
|     2    |
------------
```

I've tried with bootstrap's pull & push classes but that gave me 3-1-2 order only. Almost sure it's not possible, but maybe I'm using wrong layout in the first place?
Thanks!

Comment: I removed my answer, it didn't actually work quite how you wanted it.  Think you may need to try some absolute positioning on the medium breakpoint.

Comment: @cjd82187 thanks, I'm still working on it..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Possible to achieve this Mobile/Desktop layout using Bootstrap? (or other grid)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542303/possible-to-achieve-this-mobile-desktop-layout-using-bootstrap-or-other-grid) only change the breakpoint from 767 to 991