# IE8 non-floated div below float-right

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, twitter-bootstrap-3

foreword...

I'm looking at updating my site to use Bootstrap 3 and use responsive layout. I've noticed that the #1 browser used on the website (shockingly) is safari mobile. IE8 is #5 (just ahead of Firefox). So while IE6 + IE7 are at a combined usage of 0.9%, I have no plans of supporting them, but IE8 is still significant enought to try and figure this problem.

the problem....

I've got three divs, layout of which changes based on the screen browser width.
the setup is as follows:

html:

```
<div class="col-sm-7">#1</div>
<div class="col-sm-5 floatright">#3</div>
<div class="col-sm-7">#2</div>
```

css:

```
.floatright{float:right; clear: none;}
@media (max-width: 768px)
{    
    .floatright{float:none;}
}
```

the point of it is that the 2nd div (#3) is on the right.

there's a question that tackles this layout here [Possible to achieve this Mobile/Desktop layout using Bootstrap? (or other grid)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542303/possible-to-achieve-this-mobile-desktop-layout-using-bootstrap-or-other-grid)

The problem I'm having is that in IE8 div #2 auto-clearfixes. that is the content is not below div #1 but, way down, below div #3

caveat...

I'm using IE10 -> IE8 compatibility mode

Comment: When I try this, something quite different happens: the second div always floats, and if you make the window wider or narrower, the media query doesn't kick in, so they never end up below each other. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/MgcDU/7433/show/). Also in IE10 in IE8 compatibility mode.

Comment: there are two js libraries that help IE, html5shim and respond. This bootply shows the problem I think http://bootply.com/render/84964 (http://www.bootply.com/84964), for some reason the result looks even worse than the page i'm running it on.